# How to devide a string with regexp_extract per blank space (SQL- Athena)

Tags: sql, regex, string, extract, amazon-athena

i'm currently working on splitting a message from our webserverlog in  rows

for example:
my message (datatype string) looks like this:

`at=info method=GET path="/v1/..." host=web.com request_id=a3d71fa9-9501-4bfe-8462-54301a976d74 fwd="xxx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=167ms status=200 bytes=1114`

and i want to cut these into rows:

```
path   | service  | connect  | method | status | fwd     | dyno   |
------ | -------  | -------- | ------ | ------ | ------- | ------ | 
/v1/...|  167     |  1       |  GET   | 200    | xxx.xxx | web.1  |
```

i played around with the regexp_extract function (for the first time) on Amazon Athena in Standard SQL and already got a few row out of the string , but im struggling with a few rows.

When i try to get the for example cut the dyno out of the string im getting more info than i needed

```
 REGEXP_EXTRACT (message,'dyno=[^,]+[a-z]')AS dyno
 -> dyno=web.2 connect=0ms service=192ms status=200 bytes
```

i want have `dyno=web.1` as a result & then extract again

it would be nice if i cut the string from the start ("dyno=") till the  blank space before "connect=" but i couldn't found the right option in the sites i read.

How do i write the options to get the right piece of the string?

Comment: Why do you use `[^,]+` here? From your sample I would rather use `\S+` if your targetted string can't contain spaces or `.*?(?= connect=)`.

Comment: [^, ]+ worked on my previous rows i made before so  i  thought it will work on the other stuff

Comment: There are no commas at all in your string, so `[^,]` is rather pointless.

Answer (score 4):

Piggybagging on Sebastian's comment, I agree that `\S+` should be the solution to go forward with. So the query would look like this:

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT (message,'dyno=(\S+)',1) AS dyno
from (
  select
  'at=info method=GET path="/v1/..." host=web.com request_id=a3d71fa9-9501-4bfe-8462-54301a976d74 fwd="xxx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=167ms status=200 bytes=1114' message
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have spaces within your values (as in key-values pairs), then there is an easy solution.

```
select  msg['at']         as "at"
       ,msg['method']     as "method"
       ,msg['path']       as "path"
       ,msg['host']       as "host"
       ,msg['request_id'] as "request_id"
       ,msg['fwd']        as "fwd"
       ,msg['dyno']       as "dyno"
       ,msg['connect']    as "connect"
       ,msg['service']    as "service"
       ,msg['status']     as "status"
       ,msg['bytes']      as "bytes"

from   (select  split_to_map (message,' ','=') as msg       
        from    mytable
        )
;
```

---

```
  at  | method |   path    |  host   |              request_id              |   fwd    | dyno  | connect | service | status | bytes
------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------+---------+--------+-------
 info | GET    | "/v1/..." | web.com | a3d71fa9-9501-4bfe-8462-54301a976d74 | "xxx.xx" | web.1 | 1ms     | 167ms   | 200    | 1114
```